# Sample $k$ of $n$ numbers (with replacement), what is the probability for a certain from the $n$ numbers to be the median of the $k$ numbers

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose we have ordered numbers $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$. Now we sample $k$ of them with equal probability and with replacement and compute the median of these and call it $m$. (Let us assume that $k$ is odd for the sake of simplicity.) What is the probability the $m = a_i$ for each $i$?

I want to know this to construct the probability mass function for the median of $k$ random draws from a sample of $n$ numbers.

(Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212165/sample-k-of-n-numbers-with-replacement-what-is-the-probability-for-a-cert) but does not seem to be simple.)

Comment: I think this belongs on MathStackExchange, and I answered it there.

Comment: Thanks for answering on MathStackExchange (find link in question)!